# теряется одна строка при повторном использовании while{$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)}

Tags: php, sql, while

есть sql запрос, неважно какой:

```
$query = "SELECT * ....";
```

он выбирает 15 строчек. Дальше я хочу вывести эти строки. Рассчитывая вместительность одного блока, вывожу часть строк в этот блок:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 $vmestitelnost = 4*60;
 echo '<div id="block_1">'; создаем 1й блок
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $duration = $row['duration'];
   if($duration == 0){
    $duration = 30;
   }
   if($vmestitelnost >= $duration){
    list_tr_today($row);
    array_shift($relative_tasks);
    $vmestitelnost = $vmestitelnost-$duration;
    echo '$duration = '.$duration;
    echo '$vmestitelnost = '.$vmestitelnost;
   }
   else{
    break;
   }
  } //конец цикла while
echo '</div>';//закрываем блок, который уже не вмещает
```

в какой-то момент срабатывает указанный выше else{break;} и я начинаю выводить оставшиеся строки в уже другой блок:

```
$vmestitelnost = 4*60;
     echo '<div id="block_2">'; //создаем второй блок
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $duration = $row['duration'];
       if($duration == 0){
        $duration = 30;
       }
       if($vmestitelnost >= $duration){
        list_tr_today($row);
        array_shift($relative_tasks);
        $vmestitelnost = $vmestitelnost-$duration;
        echo '$duration = '.$duration;
        echo '$vmestitelnost = '.$vmestitelnost;
       }
       else{
        break;
       }
      } //конец цикла while echo '</div>'; //закрываем второй блок
```

между двумя этими циклами теряется одна строка

вопрос в том, как это предотвратить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$idx = 1;
printf('<div id="block_%d">', $idx++); создаем 1й блок
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $duration = $row['duration'];
  if($duration == 0){
    $duration = 30;
  }
  if($vmestitelnost < $duration) {
    // переинициализируем блок
    printf('</div><div id="block_%d">', $idx++);
  }
  list_tr_today($row);
  array_shift($relative_tasks);
  $vmestitelnost = $vmestitelnost-$duration;
  echo '$duration = '.$duration;
  echo '$vmestitelnost = '.$vmestitelnost;
} //конец цикла while
echo '</div>';//закрываем последний блок
for ($i = $idx; $i <= 4; $i++)
  printf('<div id="block_%d"></div>', $i);
```

Comment: блоки должны быть созданы В ЛЮБОМ СЛУЧАЕ. Всего 4 блока: #block_1,#block_2,#block_3,#block_4, независимо от того, пустые, или наполненные. В текущем коде новый блок создается только если вместительности предыдущего уже не хватает. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы блоки создавались в любом случае? Это можно было бы сделать, выходя из цикла. Но если выйти и начать новый, то будет потеряна строка...

Comment: @ЮрийЖулин Изменил для 4 блоков